# When did the pronunciation of ‘hierarchy’ change from /hie-/ to /hai(e)-/?

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change

I assume that ‘hierarchy’ was earlier pronounced 
/hie-/ rather than /hai(e)-/.
Is this right?  If so, when did the change occur?

Comment: *OED* has etymology: Old French *ierarchie , jerarchie*; or Italian *gerarchia*

Answer (score 2):

The sound change in *hierarchy* is consistent with the **Great Vowel Shift** (c. 1400 - 1700), which lifted /i/ to /aɪ/.

Before the Great Vowel Shift, a series of vowel changes in English that occurred gradually between 1400 and 1700, vowel spelling was relatively consistent with pronunciation. (See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) for a general overview.)

According to the [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED23832/), spellings of *hierarchy* in Middle English ranged from `jerarchi` or `gerarchi` to `herarchie`, `ierarchie`, and `iherarchie`. The [g] and [j] are artifacts from Old French ([Anglo-Norman Dictionary](http://www.anglo-norman.net/gate/)), whereas the [h] and [ie] preserve elements of the classical Latin spelling `hierarchia` ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hierarchia#Latin)). Most of the example quotations preserve the [ier] spelling.

As spelling began to standardize in the 16th and 17th centuries, English writers preferred the more classical Latin version with [hier]. The [OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/86792?redirectedFrom=hierarchy#eid) places the *hier-* spelling as from the 15th century on, and [Early English Books Online](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebogroup/) (a database of early printed texts) has results for *hierarchie* from the 16th century. By the 17th century, it appears consistently in early lexicons and dictionaries. *Hierarchie* appears in *[A Table Alphabetical](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/276/1147)* (1604) by Robert Cawdrey; *hierarchy* appears in *[A Christian Dictionary](https://leme.library.utoronto.ca/lexicon/entry/308/2995)* (1612) by Thomas Wilson.

If the lone [e] vowel had persisted from Middle English spellings, it might have shifted from /e/ to /i/. However, [ier] and [hier] as a form show up early enough (15th century) that *hierarchy* likely went from /i/ to /ai/, possibly with an intermediary step /әi/. Conventional resources on GVS state that /ai/ is well-established by about 1700, and I see no reason to except *hierarchy* from that explanation.